# Why do seeds grow upwards?

Tags: seeds, growth

Why do seeds grow upwards?  Surely gravity would pull them towards the earth's core?  Can anyone shine any light on this? Do seeds that are planted deeper grow more quickly.

Comment: While the general question is good, still, the part about "Surely gravity would pull them towards the earth's core?" could be applied widely to many other things. Why aren't _you_ pulled toward the core? Why aren't you sinking into the dirt? Why don't you grow downward? Why does water evaporate upward into the air? Why do particles get ejected _away_ from the sun? Gravity attracts, yes, but that does not mean that everything is always moving toward it at all times. If that were true, everything would collapse into tiny points and be like black holes.

Comment: one could argue that we do grow downwards, but for every bit we grow downwards, the earth pushes us back up

Comment: @Aaron  Nicely considered and said!  Yay!

Answer (score 20):

It is a reaction to gravity, it is called geotropism or gravitropism. The roots tend to grow in the direction of the gravity (positive geotropism) and the stem is going against gravity (negative geotropism).

The mechanism works with auxins, or plant growth hormones. They are pulled by gravity toward a side of the plant and will either stimulate or inhibited growth in that area.

Comment: For a longer view, reflect that plants which didn't evolve some mechanism to grow upwards (and their root systems downwards) would be pretty much restricted to floating on ponds and such.

Comment: is correct, but doesn't provide any support or citation.

Comment: @jamesqf or having a 50/50 chance of getting it right anyways.

Answer (score 19):

Because of a force known as geotropism - it is a reaction to gravity. The upward growth of shoots from seeds is known as *negative geotropism* whereas the downward growth of roots is known as *positive geotropism.*

The act of a seed to decide which way is up, or to orient itself, is geotaxis - it detects which way is down and up, in other words, because of gravitational force. see here https://www.sciencefocus.com/nature/how-do-seeds-know-which-way-to-grow/

And no, seeds which are planted deeper don't grow faster - each kind of plant seed needs to be at an optimal depth in order to germinate. Ever noticed you get lots of weed germination in freshly dug areas? That's because seeds sitting too low down in the soil which might have been there ages are moved closer to the surface by the act of digging, which then means they are now able to germinate and grow.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the geotropism mentioned in the other answers, [experiments on the ISS](https://www.livescience.com/25380-plant-growth-zero-gravity.html) have shown that plants will grow oriented in a manner such that “upward” (i.e. the stem, leaves, etc.) is toward a light source, even in the absence of gravity. Of course, this depends on the plant being able to determine which way is toward the light source. Although I have no source for this, I imagine something like a thermal gradient could be used before the plant breaks the surface.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know if there were any experiments where plants were grown on the ISS with an equal distribution of light and heat? Ex: either completely dark or completely light from all directions.

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but it’s certainly possible.

Comment: @Aaron Check out the last site I have just now included in my answer concerning zero gravity and growing plants on the ISS.  I hope I've sent enough sites to support what I am trying to say...

Comment: @alex_d  I meant to make sure I pinged you as well.  Thanks!

Comment: @stormy and alex_d: note also that I have since asked a question about this on space.SE here: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31762/have-there-been-experiments-in-space-to-determine-how-plants-grow-without-any-gr

Answer (score 0):

Gravity sure contributes to this behavior (that is to the growth vector being "up"), but none of the other answers mention moisture gradient, which is also a major contributor to the seed growth vector.

Answer (score -2):

It is probably because the plants which did this were more successful in catching light with their chlorophyll than the ones which did not do this.

More successful in growing and maturing and sprouting flowers: bigger chance of more baby plants next generation et.c.

Consider the converse: a plant that grows deeper into ground. It will clearly need some other way to get energy than by photosynthesis to survive and thrive underground. As far as I know this is not at all as common among plants.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any sources. I am just Darwinguessing.

Answer (score -3):

**Note added;** Gravity is but one factor in a 'sea' of complex factors that have effected everything living in this thin blue line on Earth.  Atmospheric pressure, temperature, humidity, the medium's porosity, the Earth's spin counterbalances the gravity and a myriad of things I didn't list or was able to mention a myriad of things we humans just do not understand about life, gravity. I am trying to say that there is no ONE thing controlling the direction of the cotyledon nor the root growth.  Roots do not grow and grow towards the earth's core.  Roots stay within the top 4 to6" of topsoil for a reason and gravity has nothing to do with it other than gravity is part and parcel of all the systems that put pressure on an organism to make it adapt to its environment and file that information away in the seed of a plant, within every living cell. As DNA.  It is weird we share 99% of the DNA messages with all animals all plants all life.  What does that tell us?

Geotropism isn't quite right because it certainly is not the only factor plants have taken into consideration.  Again, roots grow horizontally to the force of gravity, not vertically.  The fact that gravity is a constant tells us that there has to be many forces that shaped the physiology plants display. We animals are able to run and jump against and with gravity forces.

This question is a very good one because it causes us to pause, step back to think about the larger picture, a picture we humans have just begun to imagine.Geotropism seems to be a pretty minuscule reason plants grow upwards and roots grow outwards.  No one thing could ever be pointed to as the reason a life form as evolved to survive with or against. If seeds are planted too deeply (more than 3X the widest diameter of the seed) that seed will more than likely damp off with fungus and decompose. Animals are the same, we sit still too long in one place and we start decomposing, grins!

I have a feeling that people think plants are dumb like rocks.  In fact, they were here first, before animals.  Lots more time to perfect their survival abilities.

If it was up to gravity, the roots would grow and grow and grow downwards.  That is not at all what happens.  95% of all plant roots are within the top 6" of soil. The reason is water doesn't infiltrate the subsoil well at all.  Plants 'know' this fact.  Roots grow where there is air and moisture and temperature stability. There is absolutely no reason to grow any deeper roots with the exception of a few plants that need find deep water sources, chemistry for photosynthesis and/or need support. AT the same time in the desert environment, cactus don't waste any energy on deep roots!  They instead, figured out how to *store* water.  They keep their roots very shallow and very small. Deep roots would be a waste of energy and resources. They can live to 150 years, 50 feet high but their root system is just enough to keep the 2 to 10 ton plant from falling over in a wind.

There are a few plants that are programmed to have tap roots that are for support and scouting that do grow very deep. 1000's of feet deep and 1000's of feet horizontally.  They don't have the ability to store water.

The cotyledons grow upward against gravity.  They don't even need light to be persuaded.  Plants have had more time than us animals to evolve.  Gravity is like a 'positive' stressor, makes plants and animals more 'sturdy'.  But gravity certainly isn't at all the main director of plant direction of growth.

It is said that animals share 99% of DNA with plants.  That number has qualifications but what does that tell us?  Other than plants were here first, DNA or the blueprint for life started earlier plants. Before that DNA was in virus and bacteria. Plants may be stationary but they are by no means dumb as rocks.  There is life in rocks that never sees light, O2 or any organic matter; bacterium and worms.  They eat rock.  They procreate once every 1000 years.

Dr. David Attenborough stated in a documentary called "The Earth's Core" that 50% of all life is below the surface of the soil, in the crust and mantel of the earth.  I have a hard time with that statement, but heck, David Attenborough? I filed that away to deal with later.  I am thinking 'numbers' of individual lives, not biomass?

Plant DNA guides them via experience of billions of years. As long as this planet hasn't stopped spinning, lost its oceans or heaven forbid is below 150 ppm atmospheric (manmade or not) CO2, or have temperatures too low for too long, plants will thrive.  Our current CO2 at 400 ppm is getting too low.  2000 ppm was dandy.

Plants even communicate.  Via chemistry.  Some amazing instances of plants getting together for survival, such as when an animal population gets too large?  Plants that evolved to handle some grazing by those animals as a mutually beneficial symbiosis, will become toxic to those same animals.  Herds have mysteriously died within days. Then it was discovered the plants had communicated and all switched their DNA to temporarily be toxic to the animals in their environment.

Plants are not at all dumb as rocks. They are just not as well understood as animals. Cotyledons grow upward in pure darkness.  When a light is turned on off to the side, that plant will grow towards the light.  If that light is turned off and another turned on that same plant will easily change directions.  Trying to get at light necessary for further growth and survival of that plant.

There are some incredible documentaries on the life of plants. If aliens show up they will be hard pressed to decide who is smarter; humans, other animals or the plant kingdom!

[plants are smart](https://aeon.co/essays/beyond-the-animal-brain-plants-have-cognitive-capacities-too)

Also watch; "The Mind of Plants", a documentary I thought was excellent.

David Attenborough's documentary, "The Earth's Core" is a must.

[Plants grow just fine in zero gravity](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2012/121207-plants-grow-space-station-science/)

Comment: This answer doesn't address the OP's question. They asked why seeds grow upwards, and you have pointed out that indeed they do grow upwards. You talk about plants being 'intelligent', but don't explain any of the mechanisms involved in plant growth. You've also contradicted yourself (perhaps it's a typo?), you said "cotyledons grow upward against gravity", but then "gravity certainly isn't at all involved in plant direction of growth". Finally, I would like to see some citations for the "animals share 99% of DNA with plants" claim as well as the other anecdotes.

Comment: Some of this is right, some of it is wrong ("But gravity certainly isn't at all involved in plant direction of growth." is wrong), and some of it is confusingly nonsensical ("Then it was discovered the plants had communicated and all switched their DNA"). Please clarify this!

Comment: Gravity is part of the information all around us that of course affects all of life.  But it is only information.  Gravity does not tell plants HOW or where to grow.  We walk upright because we 'know' the best direction is perpendicular to the force of gravity.  Plants have been grown in zero G and that changes nothing for the growth of the roots and the growth of the photosynthetic part of the plant.

Comment: @wizzwizz4  Plants have DNA that like ours has 'switches'.  For instance, when animals find themselves in an overpopulated by their own species environment, there are 'switches' in the DNA that respond to the additional stress to tell an organism in utero to become a homosexual.  This is step one to reduce population.  DNA is more mutable or malleable than we imagine.  I think this was about a Mesquite type shrub/tree in Africa.  The plants, in response to this antelope type animal overpopulated and was decimating these trees.  All trees in the area had their DNA switched to become toxic.

Comment: I'll try to find that specific documentary; there are a few out there that talk about this very topic.  Sorry it sounds nonsensical, I'll keep trying to make sense of it for others.

Comment: @stormy The DNA doesn't change... Those "switches" aren't actual switches. Imagine DNA as a kind of set of instructions, which are followed depending on what's going on in the environment. The genes might've been "enabled", but the actual DNA wasn't changed.

Comment: @stormy Never ever try to summarise those documentaries; you'll just sound like an idiot. They already simplify it enough, even when it doesn't need "simplification" (wrongification) so without the inherent credibility of being a documentary you'll just be embarrassingly wrong. I speak from experience, if you're wondering; it took a while for people to stop teasing me about my "explanation of E=mc^2, the black hole theorem". What you're saying kind of sounds like an approximation of correct, but it's already explained by lots of other people.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85264/discussion-between-stormy-and-wizzwizz4).

Comment: "But gravity certainly isn't at all involved in plant direction of growth" - this sentence is totally incorrect.

Comment: Another error here is the statement that "water doesn't infiltrate the subsoil well at all".  That's true for some soils, but by no means all.  For instance, in spring or stream-fed meadows, the water may be coming up from the subsoil, or plants may grow deep roots to access subsurface water.

Comment: I am an expert where plants are concerned, including soil science.  Water does not infiltrate compacted sub soils well...the horizons below topsoil.  Water coming up from the subsoil would mean wet lands, marsh.  Plants will not grow deep roots unless they are genetically predisposed to HAVE large root systems.  Such as cool season grass mixes for lawns.  One can 'train' the root systems to grow deeper by deep watering and then allowing the soil to dry out from the top down.  Poa annua for instance, a weed grass with shallow root systems used a lot on golf courses will not grow deep roots...

Comment: This question demonstrates the need to back up and fill in a bit of logical science.  My goodness the nit picking.  Please substantiate WHY such and such is in error.  I am talking on a scale of what is important and what is not.  Yeah, let's just go with 'geotropism'...nice scientific sounding label that is black and white and works. Grins.

Comment: @Ben I need to learn to be more PC.  Gravity of course is involved in plant growth but as I've shown?? is a minuscule force.  But it most certainly is there and I was in error saying the words "is not at all involved" in plant direction of growth.

Comment: @jamesqf water tables are independent of soils,  High water tables will cause even genetically disposed plants with deep roots to grow shallow roots.  I am sorry I didn't word that comment better.  I doubt one would find in a natural ecosystem plants with large root systems growing where there is a high water table, a marsh, a bog.  Roots not adapted to aquatic situations would simply not flourish and not be found where there are high water tables or influence by surface water systems.  Roots grown in water are different than roots meant to grow in soil. Wet land habitats are not the norm.

Comment: stormy: late last week I asked a question related to this on space.SE about ISS experiments on this topic, and I got a good answer: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31762/have-there-been-experiments-in-space-to-determine-how-plants-grow-without-any-gr

Comment: Also, I want to +1 your answer but I do not know enough personally, and the other comments have dissuaded me from doing so. However, I'm not going to vote it down either. If it is any consolation, I thank you for providing more information, and that is the most important thing.

Comment: @Aaron I love your honesty.  I am glad you think enough of my line of thought to not mark me down.  I've got plenty of points to lose and not at all afraid to lose them.  We humans have a tough time thinking, linking information to other information to make information more credible.  Part of that is this negative feedback towards thinkers like myself.  I know you brought up ISS and that is why I sent this rather pronounced site everyone could have looked up and read to support my words and your assertions!  It is not much fun being the rebel.  I will never 'mimic' someone else's thoughts.

Comment: I am not merely nit-picking when I say that it is wrong that plants are not affected by gravity. It has a very significant effect on plant growth. Not that gravity forces the direction in which the plant grows - rather plants use gravity to detect and respond to their orientation, with some parts of the plant having mechanisms which direct their growth towards or away from the earth. This is the meaning of the word "geotropism" - which can be positive or negative - towards or away from the earth. While this is not the only thing plants detect, it is an important factor.

Comment: @Ben  We humans have problems in zero gravity, they, the scientists don't think we humans will be able to procreate in zero gravity.  But we shall go through the motions just fine.  if gravity were such a big deal to plants, why would they be able to grow in zero g?  My answers are just getting longer and longer trying to explain how I understand a problem or question.  I need a serious course on conciseness....when discussing live organisms, I have a hard time with short answers.   Again, how do plants deal with zero gravity so well?

Comment: @stormy The question that Aaron links answers this very clearly: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31762/have-there-been-experiments-in-space-to-determine-how-plants-grow-without-any-gr The stem has to come out in some direction; if there is no gravity, it just keeps growing in roughly that direction, because it doesn't have the cue (gravity) to tell it which way to go. They don't actually deal with zero gravity so well, as that answer also discusses.

Comment: I read all of those excerpts from Dr. Sheldon.  The point is plants are programmed to grow in the gravity in which they evolved.  But, they most certainly can grow in zero gravity.  Not well, but they can still adapt in zero gravity to a certain extent.  Of course gravity and normal conditions one has evolved with will ensure more success but zero or minimal gravity is not a 'deal breaker'.  To say gravity is direly important is just...just...not quite right.  The seed has programing to tell the photosynthetic part to grow 'away' from the roots which has been shown.

Comment: Plants can grow in 0g because they have many mechanisms for orientation, I never said geotropism was the only mechanism, or even an essential mechanism. I would be happy to edit your answer for conciseness, if you like, but I fear you might not like the result.

Comment: @Ben, knock yourself out.  Edit away.  If I don't like it I shall re edit what you edited.  Ugh, I made an error saying gravity isn't important, when of course it is.  I have tried to mitigate that statement but I don't think throwing the baby out with the bath water is necessary?

Comment: I have tried an edit - but I'm afraid it may be rather too drastic. I did try to keep most of your points, and not add any additional information, but I am not sure if it is still true to your original intent.

Comment: ummmm @Ben how do I check out your edit?  Thank you for editing by the way!  I'll get to understand you better!  I'll go and try to find this edit or is this edit already showing as my answer?  No problem.  and thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where my edit is, I don't have a lot of rep on this stack, so I got a message that it was being "peer reviewed"

Comment: Peer reviewed, huh?  They should be happy you took the time, Ben!  I'll watch for your edit.  I might just remove my answer, that usually makes everyone happy, grins!  Thank you again.